# How can I write a shell script in windows to create a new excel sheet from a template?

Tags: excel, windows, batch-file

I'm attempting to write a shell script for the Windows OS that will create some new files/directories, as well as create a new excel sheet that is based on a template. I've run into a few problems:

- I don't necessarily want to run excel, I just want to create a file based on a template. I'm not sure what command I'd use to do this. I know how to boot excel, but I don't know if it's possible to create a new sheet from a template from the command prompt.
- I want to create a file called README.md, with the name of the directory at the beginning of the text file. I know how to do this in the command prompt, but it requires "ctrl + z" to execute. How would I get this to execute on a shell script?

Here is my code:

```
cd Downloads\Lab
mkdir %1
:: copy Item_List.xltx 

cd %1
mkdir media print_Files 
type nul > .gitignore.txt
type nul > README.md
cd ..
```

Thank you.

Comment: `cd %1`, `type nul`? Looks like a `cmd` script to me. Note that `cmd`/`batch` is totally different from `bash` (usually used on Linux). You may want to correct your tags by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: @Socowi fixed, thank you.